# iOS folder like autolayout

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, autolayout

How do I make iOS folder-like behavior using auto layout?
It works like that for different devices:

- on iPhone 5 etc(320) it's almost whole screen width
- on iPhone 6 it's smaller part of the screen
- on iPad it's even smaller

So it's not like linear percentage of the screen size.
Everywhere it's on the screen center.
How do I do that using auto layout?

Note: folder-like it's like width of the folder for apps on main screens

Comment: What do you mean by ""iOS folder-like behavior"?

Comment: folder for apps on the main screens

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what that means. What "main screens" are you talking about? And what folders? Give an example.

Comment: @rdelmar I guess he means the Springboard Apps folder